# Iterate AWS json response python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Trying to iterate thru an AWS json output and check if a specific version exist in ECR using the below code. But I am always getting "Image does not exist in ECR!" even when the image tag exist.

```
client = boto3.client('ecr')
response = client.list_images(registryId='my_account_number', repositoryName='my_app')

for i in response['imageIds']:
    if i['imageTag'] != version:
        print(response)
        print('Image does not exist in ECR!')
        quit()
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: `if ['imageTag'] != version:` I think you meant `i['imageTag']`?

Comment: Yes.. Adjusted the above.. same result

Comment: Then debug it. Add `print(i['imageTag'])`. We can't debug it for you as we don't have the response you are getting.

Comment: Ok, it's only returning the first image tag and not the others. So it seems I am missing some code so it goes thru all the image tags.

Comment: That is because as soon as you find the first non-matching image(in this case, the first one), you quit. Instead, you need to go until you find a matching version and then quit.

Comment: Ok I see.. Looking better now removing the quit statement.. But I get 'Image does not exist in ECR!' for all image tags till it finds the right one.. Is there a way to have it just print once if it can't match the version..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to run until it finds the version you are expecting:

```
client = boto3.client('ecr')
response = client.list_images(registryId='my_account_number', repositoryName='my_app')

for i in response['imageIds']:
    if i['imageTag'] == version:
        print('Found matching version!')
        print(i)
        break
else:
    print('Image does not exist in ECR!')
```

If the correct version is not found, `'Image does not exist in ECR!'` will be printed.